# user can login in terminal window but cannot in lightdm

Tags: debian, lightdm

I have installed a new system using debian and I have copied the /home directory from the previously user disk, using rsync. Then I have created two user accounts using useradd and I have set a password using passwd.

The first user can log in in a terminal window and also in the greeting page generated by lightdm. In contrast, the second user cannot log in in the lightdm window, but he can on the terminal window.

What can be wrong and what is the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the reason of the problem and to solve it.

The installed **lightdm** has used the English keyboard layout, although I have a German layout here. An important difference is that the letters Z and Y are interchanged. It was easy to verify that this situation existed while entering characters in the **username** field of the lightdm login window. The displayed characters were not translated according to the German layout. Entering Z was displayed as Y.

The first user was able to login using **lightdm** because her password used only characters which are at the same place on the English and on the German keyboard layout. But this was not the case of the second user, therefore the entered password was wrong because the user assumed that the German layout was in use.

The solution was to set

```
[Seat:*] 
display-setup-script=/usr/bin/setxkbmap de
```

in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf. It was commented out before.